# Is there any way to create a write-able volume in non-root docker container?

Tags: docker

I have pull an image from Jenkins official docker hub.

But the container I created do not have root permission.

I can't change anything in my share volume inside the container

Here is my running command

```
docker run -itd -v /home/user/docker:/home/host -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Is there any way to make this path "/home/host" write-able in the container?

Comment: Did you run Jenkins container with root?

Comment: yes, but it seems not to impact the permission inside the container

Answer (score 2):

The [Jenkins docker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#usage) usage does include:

> NOTE: Avoid using a bind mount from a folder on the host machine into `/var/jenkins_home`, as this might result in file permission issues (the user used inside the container might not have rights to the folder on the host machine).
>
> If you really need to bind mount `jenkins_home`, ensure that the directory on the host is accessible by the jenkins user inside the container (jenkins user - `uid 1000`) or **`use -u some_other_user`** parameter with docker run.

```
docker run -d -u aKnownUser -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The alternative is to leave docker create a named volume:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```